# If statement inside a switch case in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there are a couple of questions like this on stack overflow but the problem is that it does not solve my answer.

I want to show an if-statement inside a switch case.

Here is my code

```
 NSMutableArray *stdMarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"100", @"70", @"97", @"11", @"59", nil];

    int marksObtained;

    for (int i= 0; i < [stdMarks count]; i++) {
        marksObtained += [[stdMarks objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    }

    int totalMarks = 500;
    int percentage = (marksObtained * 100)/totalMarks;

    NSLog(@"The total marks are: %d", marksObtained);
    NSLog(@"The percentage is: %d", percentage);
    NSLog(@"The total numbers of subjects are: %d", [stdMarks count]);


    switch (percentage) {
        case 1:
            if (percentage >= 70) {
                NSLog(@"You get 50 percent fee concession");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (percentage >= 60) {
                NSLog(@"You get 45 percent fee concession");
            }
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"you do not qualify");
            break;
    }
```

No matter what the percentage is I always get the default answer "You do not qualify".

What am I doing wrong

Please help me out here

Comment: here no need of switch case , if condition take care of every action

Comment: what are the cases of this switch? Just `percentage == 1` and `percentage == 2`?

Comment: There can be more cases, I have just written 2 cases for now and the percentage which I am getting is more than 70. In this case it should print out case1 but it is still giving the default answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if your percentage is not equal to run 1 or 2, it will go to default.

```
switch (percentage) { <---- this percentage, you only provide the case of 1 and 2.
        case 1:
            if (percentage >= 70) {
                NSLog(@"You get 50 percent fee concession");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (percentage >= 60) {
                NSLog(@"You get 45 percent fee concession");
            }
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"you do not qualify");
            break;
    }
```

guessing you need to change the percentage in switch(percentage).

Updated:

```
if (percentage >= 70) {
    NSLog(@"You get 50 percent fee concession");
}
else if (percentage >= 60) {
    NSLog(@"You get 45 percent fee concession");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"you do not qualify");
}
```

update:
if you want to do it using switch case:
for percentage >= 70

```
switch (percentage)
case 70:
case 71:
case 72:
case 73:
.
.
.
case 100:
NSLog(@"You get 50 percent fee concession");
break;
case 60:
.
.
.
```

and so on which is very stupid , so a if else case is more suitable

Comment: If I get the % more than 70, it still gives the default answer

Comment: cause if percentage > 3 
it wont fall in case 1 and case 2 and goes default

Comment: okay understood your point....but then how can I do it properly. For e.g. I want to show if user gets more than 70% it should print the 1st case. So whatever the % is between 100 - 70 how will the 1st case be printed? Do I have to write individual % for each case?

Can you show in code please?

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh please check my update, no switch case is needed

Comment: I have done it in if but I wanted to know how could this be achieved in switch case....thanks anyway

Comment: a switch case is for some exact condition. if you want to do it using switch case need to do something very stupid, see my update

Answer (score 2):

that is because the switch is being fed the `percentage` which only caters for 1 and 2 percent, so those if statements will never fire because to get into those cases, they have to be lower then the values in the if statements

my suggestion is to drop the switch statement, because it seems unnecessary, just have if/else statements that encompass the ranges you want

Comment: Even f I get the 70% or more, it still gives the default answer

Comment: Yes, because only 1% and 2% will go to the two cases. 70% goes to "default"

Comment: okay understood your point....but then how can I do it properly. For e.g. I want to show if user gets more than 70% it should print the 1st case.

So whatever the % is between 100 - 70 how will the 1st case be printed?

Comment: take out the switch and just leave the if statements, the switch just isnt the right tool for the job here